# Compiling .tex files with space in the name does not work in Texshop 4.44

Tags: texshop, macos

This morning, I ran TeX Live Utility to update all packages. I don't know if it is a coincidence but right after that all my .tex files would not compile in Texshop 4.44. I always got the same message : "Latex error: Missing \begin{document}". Evidently, that \begin{document} was there...

After exploring a lot of possibility, I tried removing the spaces in my .tex filenames and everything started working fine.

I have three questions :
1) Has anyone seen the same behavior?
2) Where, in Texshop could be the problem?
3) Is it really necessary to remove spaces in filenames? It used to work fine before.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Whatever answer you will finally get ... Spaces in filenames is always a bad choice. Even if MS Windows accept that (sometimes) and have made many people use that inside their document names or folders, linux (and thus mac) will possibly give some errors... Programmers could overcome these kind of errors and even many linux programs do that. But why to add all this code just to make their programs adapt this bad behavior that MS made a bad habit to many people? Even if you try to use overleaf... you could possibly fail to compile... I think it is a good opportunity for you to fix this problem.

Comment: @koleygr is correct that supporting spaces adds a vast amount of code, for really only cosmetic benefit, but that said, the code we added was supposed to work....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle +1 ... But I had to say that ... Also a question? Whould that work for the current file? or for a figure with spaces too (as an example)... For linux this would solve the problem but even after that you should add some ugly `\\` to complete the name and compile....

Comment: @koleygr figure and input files with spaces should work in the current release but `\jobname` is auto-quoted and the expansion timing is a bit different so the extra quotes added to support space get added on top so if `\jobname` is `"one two"` latex ends up trying to open `""one two".aux"` and the space ends up unquoted, the  7`\expandafter` below re-arrange the expansion order so things work out,

Comment: Thanks for this info @DavidCarlisle ... This kind of "vast code" is useful for learning purposes anyway... So (+1) to the question too (thanks to you!)

Comment: I have to agree with all of you about the energy and code needed to permit spaces in filenames but, being a freshman year physics teacher trying to convince my students to use latex for their school reports I will say that I'd rather not have to had this constraint. Over 2 years my rate of success is growing and I would'nt want to add this to the difficulties... By the way, you'd be surprised at how fast they learn and become advocate of the tool!

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX2e 2018-10-01 Patch Level 3 has been updated to ctan today and will appear in distributions in a few days, it contains code equivalent to the fix below.

---

**old answer**

If you add this to the top of your file:

```
\makeatletter
\def\set@curr@file#1{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\@curr@file{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\unquote@name
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\string
        \csname\@firstofone#1\@empty\endcsname}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
```

you should find it works, let me know if not:  this definition is planned for the next release,

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, your fix does a perfect job. Thanks also for your fast response.

Comment: @BernardMarcheterre thanks for the confirmation

Comment: As of this morning, after updating with TeX Live Utility, the problem is now solved! Thank you @DavidCarlisle !